# Filter lookup inside a Dialog- CRM 2015 Online

Tags: process, dialog, dynamics-crm-2015, filtered-lookup

How can we filter a lookup that is in a page of the dialog process. 
E.g. I have a lookup to "incident" on Prompt and Response, I would like to filter it based on the value of a field in incident entity.

I tried:

- Creating new views, also setting it as default.
- addPreSearch and addCustomFilter on the field on the form(Not sure how to use these scripts inside the Dialog)

Any Ideas ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not possible.

As an alternative you could consider adding a query to the dialog and a page with a prompt having an *Option Set (picklist)* response type.

Comment: Thanks Henk
I tried this and it works.
However, there might be hundreds of records in a lookup and it might not be feasible put them in a pick list.

Comment: I'm afraid that's the most you can get using dialogs. Your next option would be a custom HTML web resource and build your wizard from the ground up.

Comment: I agree with you on this, we modified the process a bit for this. Thanks Henk!